# how can i add click functionality to gmap3 function?

Tags: javascript, marker, jquery-gmap3

I am using gmap 3 for plotting map. i need to enable on click functionality on marker.
am using the following code

```
var contact = {"lat":"26.207293", "lon":"50.583730"}; //Change a map coordinate here!
  try {
    var mapContainer = $('.map');
    mapContainer.gmap3({
      action: 'addMarker',
      marker:{
        options:{
          icon : new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/assets/marker.png')
        }
      },
      latLng: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
      map:{
        center: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
        zoom: 14
        },
      },
      {action: 'setOptions', args:[{scrollwheel:false}]}
    );
  } catch(err) {

  }
```

i tried this too.eventes function.still not woring.

```
events:{
              click:function(){
                alert("I'm the last one, and i have my own click event");
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code, and changed a few things. This works:

```
var contact = {"lat":"26.207293", "lon":"50.583730"}; //Change a map coordinate here!
$("#my_map").gmap3({
  marker:{
    values: [[contact.lat, contact.lon]],
    options: {
      draggable: false
    },
    events:{
      click: function() {
        alert('bla');
      }
    }
  },
  map: {
    options: {
      center: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
      zoom: 14
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aJuBZ/